# how to read this text from file

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

how to read the text below?

> ‰€ˆ‡‰�#îõ‘þüŠ ê‘¯õù ‚†ƒ� -#�ª÷‘þü “‘
>   ª“îù )øþ¦ùý ¤ª—ùý î‘õ•þø—¤(#•¢þ¢�
>   ø¤÷¢ù ê‘¯õù îõ‘þü#^a—ú¤�ö^b•¦øû÷¢ð‘ö
>   ¤�ù ¢�÷©^cˆˆƒ�#‚€� «.: õ¬ø¤Š
>   ›¢øñ#…�…ˆí/Š…/
>   …€�…Š}TK{^aˆˆƒ�#†/„€€#}BF{#ª“îùû‘ý
>   î‘õ•þø—¤ý#ª“îùû‘ý î‘õ•þø—¤ý --
>   �¥õøöû‘#^c

I use this code but not display all characters

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(open.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 ;
        byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        string text = enc.GetString(data);
```

and show text :

> â€ â€°â‚¬Ë†â€¡â€°Â�#Ã®Ãµâ� �˜Ã¾Ã¼Å
>   Ãªâ€˜Â¯ÃµÃ¹ â€šâ€ Æ’Â� -#Â�ÂªÃ·â€˜Ã¾Ã¼
>   â€œâ€˜ Âªâ€œÃ®Ã¹ )Ã¸Ã¾Â¦Ã¹Ã½
>   Â¤Âªâ€”Ã¹Ã½ Ã®â€˜Ãµâ€¢Ã¾Ã¸â€”Â¤(#â€�
>   �Â¢Ã¾Â¢Â� Ã¸Â¤Ã·Â¢Ã¹ Ãªâ€˜Â¯ÃµÃ¹
>   Ã®Ãµâ€˜Ã¾Ã¼#^aâ€”ÃºÂ¤Â�Ã¶
>   ^bâ€¢Â¦Ã¸Ã»Ã·Â¢Ã°â€˜Ã¶ Â¤Â�Ã¹
>   Â¢Â�Ã·Â©^cË†Ë†Æ’Â�#â€šâ‚ ¬Â� Â«.:
>   ÃµÂ¬Ã¸Â¤Å â€ºÂ¢Ã¸Ã±#â€¦Â�â€¦Ë†Ã­/Å
>   â€¦/ â€¦â‚¬Â�â€¦Å }TK{^aË†Ë†Æ’Â�#â€
>   /â€žâ‚¬â‚¬#}BF{#Âªâ€œÃ®Ã¹Ã» â€˜Ã½
>   Ã®â€˜Ãµâ€¢Ã¾Ã¸â€”Â¤Ã½#Â�
>   �â€œÃ®Ã¹Ã»â€˜Ã½ Ã®â€˜Ãµ

**this is a TEXT DOS**
and encoding this text is:

```
IBM037

IBM437

IBM500

ASMO-708

DOS-720

ibm737

ibm775

ibm850

ibm852

IBM855

ibm857

IBM00858

IBM860

ibm861

DOS-862

IBM863

IBM864

IBM865

cp866

ibm869

IBM870

windows-874

cp875

shift_jis

gb2312

ks_c_5601-1987

big5

IBM1026

IBM01047

IBM01140

IBM01141

IBM01142

IBM01143

IBM01144


IBM01145

IBM01146

IBM01147

IBM01148

IBM01149

utf-16

unicodeFFFE

windows-1250

windows-1251

Windows-1252

windows-1253

windows-1254

windows-1255

windows-1256

windows-1257

windows-1258

Johab

macintosh

x-mac-japanese

x-mac-chinesetrad

x-mac-korean

x-mac-arabic

x-mac-hebrew

x-mac-greek

x-mac-cyrillic



x-mac-chinesesimp

x-mac-romanian

x-mac-ukrainian

x-mac-thai

x-mac-ce

x-mac-icelandic

x-mac-turkish

x-mac-croatian

utf-32

utf-32BE

x-Chinese-CNS

x-cp20001

x-Chinese-Eten

x-cp20003

x-cp20004

x-cp20005

x-IA5

x-IA5-German

x-IA5-Swedish

x-IA5-Norwegian

us-ascii

x-cp20261

x-cp20269

IBM273

IBM277

IBM278

IBM280

IBM284

IBM285

IBM290

IBM297

IBM420

IBM423

IBM424

x-EBCDIC-KoreanExtended

IBM-Thai

koi8-r

IBM871

IBM880

IBM905

IBM00924

EUC-JP

x-cp20936

x-cp20949

cp1025

koi8-u

iso-8859-1

iso-8859-2

iso-8859-3

iso-8859-4

iso-8859-5

iso-8859-6

iso-8859-7

iso-8859-8

iso-8859-9

iso-8859-13

iso-8859-15

x-Europa

iso-8859-8-i

iso-2022-jp

csISO2022JP

iso-2022-jp

iso-2022-kr

x-cp50227

euc-jp

EUC-CN

euc-kr

hz-gb-2312

GB18030

x-iscii-de

x-iscii-be

x-iscii-ta

x-iscii-te

x-iscii-as

x-iscii-or

x-iscii-ka

x-iscii-ma

x-iscii-gu

x-iscii-pa

utf-7

utf-8
```

Comment: What language is it supposed to be in?  It isn't UTF8.  Maybe offer a link to the original file?  Both texts look like gibberish from stackoverflow.

Comment: @Ignacio: He's probably on Windows and has no idea what you're talking about.  (unless you're commenting to tofutim?)

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Comment: This is not answerable. Post the (beginning of) a file in Hex (or base64) notation, preferably with a known outcome.

Answer (score 3):

To read the file you need to know what encoding used in this file.

If you don't know, you can iterate through all encodings and see if find the one that works.

```
const string FileName = "FileName";
foreach (var encodingInfo in Encoding.GetEncodings())
{
    try
    {
        var encoding = encodingInfo.GetEncoding();
        var text = File.ReadAllText(FileName, encoding);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", encodingInfo.Name, text.Substring(0, 20));

        // put break point and check if text is readable here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed: {0}", encodingInfo.Name);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: assuming this is a text file, assuming the file isn't huge.

Comment: You could write the encoding name and the first 20-30 characters of the encoding, in a file. I think it would be easier to pinpoint the correct one, rather than stepping in the debugger through all of them.

Comment: @Liviu Trifoi - I would agree if I knew what kind of characters are inside. What if this is Arabic, or Chinese. Those will not show properly in console if console encoding is not set. There are not that many encodings to iterate through, I would just do it in debugger to rule out console display issues.

Comment: @user764499 - Can you upload your file somewhere? For example http://hotfile.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you're trying to open a .dat file, which is probably written with a byte format by the looks of it

Try the following code

```
        File readThis = new File("file directory");
        byte[] aByte = new byte[(int)readThis.length()];
        FileInputStream Fis = new FileInputStream(readThis);
        Fis.read(aByte);
        System.out.println(Contents: "+aByte);
        Fis.close();
```

Let me know how it goes :)